# Jenkin failed to spawn new process during build on Mac system

Tags: jenkins, npm, build, jenkins-pipeline

We have a react native app and we configured it with Jenkins for CI/CD .While running the npm install command via Jenkins from the build window (execute shell) its getting failed .
Am using node : v10.16.3 and npm  : 6.9.0 with latest jenkins version.

This is the logs for the last run

```
15:52:30 [cavionnovus-IOS] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins5253804416691912910.sh
15:52:30 + export PATH=/usr/local/bin
15:52:30 + PATH=/usr/local/bin
15:52:30 + npm install
15:52:34 npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
15:52:36 npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
15:52:40 npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
15:53:47 
15:53:47 > fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/cavionnovus-IOS/node_modules/fsevents
15:53:47 > node install
15:53:47 
15:53:47 
15:53:47 > grpc@1.23.3 install /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/cavionnovus-IOS/node_modules/grpc
15:53:47 > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
15:53:47 
15:53:48 npm WARN react-navigation-stack@1.9.4 requires a peer of react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
15:53:48 npm WARN react-navigation-drawer@2.2.2 requires a peer of react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
15:53:48 npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
15:53:48 npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
15:53:48 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
15:53:48 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
15:53:48 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn sh ENOENT
15:53:48 
15:53:48 npm ERR! file sh
15:53:48 npm ERR! path sh
15:53:48 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
15:53:48 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
15:53:48 npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
15:53:48 npm ERR! grpc@1.23.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
15:53:48 npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
15:53:48 npm ERR! 
15:53:48 npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.23.3 install script.
15:53:48 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

There wont be any issues while running the same on windows machine , the isssue not there while running the npm commands from the jenkins workspace manualy .
So from the logs i think jenkins blocking creating new process from the build .
while running the command manually we could see that the dependency grpc is downloaded via remotely . that may be a new process and jenkin blocks / kill that child process.

This is the command i used on the build window of Jenkin

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
$sudo npm install
```

please help me to get ride of this issue .

Comment: Is your company using private registry? or default public registry? If private registry, make sure 'registry' in npm config is set properly in Jenkins. You can also put ".npmrc" file with required config.

Comment: @RamBabuS : we are not using any registry

Comment: can you try installing updated version globally in your jenkins slave `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: @RamBabuS: the npm command works while trying out the same from the workspace as Different system user(username:Test) .but not working with Jenkins as SYSTEM user . So how can we run the Jenkins job as System logged user (Test) instead of SYSTEM